# xinetd + shell script echoing flags in TCP packet

Tags: shell-script, networking, xinetd

I'm trying to create a script that replicates a JSON status response from a Minecraft server (https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping). I've currently set up `xinetd` to execute a shell script that echos a preset back, but I'm having trouble crafting the TCP packet. For some reason it returns whatever comes after `echo`, ignoring any flags. Here's a stripped down case that replicates the issue:

`/usr/bin/mc`

```
#!/bin/sh

# hello!
echo -en "\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x21"
```

`/etc/xinetd.d/minecraft`

```
service minecraft
{
  type = UNLISTED
  instances = 20
  socket_type = stream
  protocol = tcp
  wait = no
  user = root
  group = root
  server = /usr/bin/mc
  port = 25565
  disable = no
}
```

TCP reply data as seen from the client that initiated the request:

```
00000000: 2d65 6e20 5c78 3638 5c78 3635 5c78 3663  -en \x68\x65\x6c
00000010: 5c78 3663 5c78 3666 5c78 3231 0a         \x6c\x6f\x21.
```

Do I need to read the client request first, or is `echo` aliased to something else if called from `xinetd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` is an internal shell command. If you change the first line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The program will work because `echo` from `bash` understands `-en`.

Otherwise, you have to see which shell is actually `/bin/sh` in your system and use the proper syntax for its `echo` command.